# Added Daily Partition before the insert

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, partition, database-partitioning

i have the following table

```
    CREATE TABLE "ICTPART_DAILY_SUMMARY" 
   (    
   
   "EVENT_START_DATE" DATE
   "ACCOUNTING_METHOD" CHAR(1), 
    ......etc 
    )
PARTITION BY RANGE ("EVENT_START_DATE") 
 (PARTITION "ICTPART_DAY_SUM_P20220218"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2022-02-219 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  TABLESPACE "TBS_ICTQUO_D" , 
PARTITION "ICTPART_DAY_SUM_P20220219"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2022-02-20 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "TBS_ICTQUO_D" , 
PARTITION "ICTPART_DAY_SUM_PMAX"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  TABLESPACE "TBS_ICTQUO_D" ) ;
```

my job run everyday morning and insert new lines to this table
i want to add partition everyday before insert the new line when my job starts
i mean before the insert please.

any ideas about that please ? and i need to keep the name of the partition like that one `"ICTPART_DAY_SUM_P20220219"` with changes of the day of course `P20220220` .. etc

Answer (score 3):

You can use the alter table split partition, like this:

```
alter table ICTPART_DAILY_SUMMARY split partition ICTPART_DAY_SUM_PMAX at (to_date('20220220','yyyymmdd'))) into (partition ICTPART_DAY_SUM_P20220219, partition ICTPART_DAY_SUM_PMAX)
```

Look at the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877).
You can also use interval partitioning :

```
PARTITION BY RANGE ("EVENT_START_DATE") interval(numtodsinterval(1,'day'))
```

this will create the partition for you automatically, although you cannot control the partition name. And you do not need to know the name of the partition to manage it, you just need to know a value in the 'range', for example:

```
alter table ICTPART_DAILY_SUMMARY truncate partition for (to_date('01012022','ddmmyyyy'))
```